# Efficiently represent 16777217 as a float

Tags: floating-point

Browsing job advertisements, I saw the following question:

> Do you understand what it takes to efficiently represent `16,777,217` as a float? [Siemens]

I don't understand the question. I know that `16,777,216 = 224` is the last integer in the sequence `[0, 1, ..., N]` that can be represented as a float exactly. How can `16,777,217` be represented as a float "efficiently"? `16,777,216 + 1`? But that's two floats.

Please give a hint.

Comment: "16,777,216 = 2^24 is the last integer that can be represented as a float exactly" Not really. There is no problem representing larger numbers like, say 2^100, provided only zeroes are stripped by rounding. Besides that I do not understand either what means "efficiently".

Comment: @AlainMerigot, my statement was indeed inaccurate. `16777218` can also be represented exactly. I meant the largest number `N` in the sequence `[0, 1, ..., N]`.

Comment: Perhaps the answer they're looking for is "No you can't?" Knowing this number is not precisely representable as a single-precision float would demonstrate above-average knowledge of floating-point numbers.

Comment: @alias I like the question and, though slightly disappointing, I believe that your comment is actually an appropriate answer (taking the scope of unbroken consecutive integer sequence into account). Would you create one?

Comment: @Yunnosch, but then it is not clear what "efficiently" means. Can you represent? I can't. Can you do it *efficiently*? What does "efficiently" mean? I'm looking for a catch in the question, but maybe there is no catch at all.

Comment: The comment by alias is the key. If the answer is not the details of doing it, but instead that there is a serious problem with it, then the "efficient" is just there to camouflage the otherwise to obvious trick question of simply asking "How is it possible?" which is just an open version of the yes/no question "Is it possible?". Maybe that assumption should explicitly be added to the answer, but I would even accept it if it is implicit.

Comment: They are probably getting a feel for how much of a language lawyer you are. If you are a hardcore language lawyer, then you are living in a dream world where you don't necessarily know the floating point representation, so you can't make any assumptions, whatsoever. If you are a realist, then you will jump to the conclusion that it is IEEE-754 single precision "float" (as in C float), and you will reply that you can't do that, it's not possible.

Comment: A related question, not as sly/tricky, but probing just about the same aspects of an applicant's knowledge of floating point, is "[What's the largest odd float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267201)"  (Answer: 16777215.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on fairly extensive interview experience, I think this a question designed to initiate an open-ended technical discussion that draws on a candidate's breadth of knowledge and experience, creativity and capability to think "outside the box", and the willingness to ask questions to establish applicable context restrictions and trade-offs. In particular, the words "efficient", "represent", and "float" are all subject to interpretation.

What exactly does "float" mean? If one assumes that "float" refers to a data object of type `float` in C whose internal representation is the IEEE-754 `binary32` format, then the answer is that it is not possible to store 16,777,217 without loss of accuracy, as the closest available encodings are `0x1.000000p+24` (16,777,216) and `0x1.000002p+24` (16,777,218).

However, the ISO-C standard does not mandate use of IEEE-754, and we might be looking at a hypothetical C implementation on ancient 36-bit machines such as the IBM 7090 or the Honeywell 6000 series, where `float` is mapped to the hardware's 36-bit single-precision format with 27 significand bits (most significant bit stored explicitly). Or in a more modern context, one might be working with an FPGA-based processor that uses a 40-bit floating-point format with a 31-bit stored significand for `float`. In either of these scenarios, the value 16,777,217 can be stored accurately in a `float`.

What exactly does "represent" mean? One might be working in an environment where for some reason all data is stored in `float`s comprising 32 bits. Using a 32-bit two's complement representation, the bit pattern corresponding to 16,777,217 is 0x01000001 and this bit pattern can be transferred to a `float` with `memcpy()`, and re-interpreted later into an integer *on-the-fly* at the point of use.

What exactly does "efficient" mean? For example, a given use case might only require positive floating-point operands, and one could therefore reuse the sign bit of `binary32` operands to store an additional least significant significand bit, allowing lossless storage of the value 16,777,217. At the point of use, the sign bit would be used to expand the operand *on-the-fly* into a mid-section significand bit in a `double` or the tail element of a `float`-pair representation before applying the absolute value. For use cases that are largely bound by memory access, thus preferring the use of narrow storage types, this might be considered efficient despite the increased cost of computation due to the cost of executing additional instructions for unpacking and computation.

Other variants of compression are possible. For example, repeated leading significand bits can be compressed out for storage purposes if all `float` operands are close to powers of two. I actually used something like this for a processor extension with certain specialized instructions, where one operand was known to be always close to unity, allowing floating-point operands with 32 significand bits to be transported between these instructions using the IEEE-754 `binary32` format. In that case compression and decompression was performed in hardware, so very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

add a single bit to the significand

Comment: Patch a CPU? ;)

Comment: Siemens makes networking equipment, and other "low level" gear.  This type of equipment, for latency and economic reasons, often has many things done "in hardware" (so a CPU might not be directly involved) using FPGAs/ASICS/etc. What's a better answer?  Can you see why my answer addresses "efficiency"?  :-)